# Can I explicitly undefine a macro for particular function?

Tags: c++, windows, c-preprocessor

I've written a template function to perform a quick log base 2 of an integer.  It works in my test program but when I pasted it into my main project I found I had an issue with the `windows.h` header.  The issue is that I'm using the c++ `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` function but `windows.h` includes a macro also called `max` which, being a macro, is not namespace aware and overrides my attempt to use the real C++ function.  Is there anyway I can avoid this other than by not including `windows.h`? (which isn't really an option)

Here's my function:

```
// Returns x where x = log2(n)
template<typename T>
T log2i(T n)
{
    static const T infinite(std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    T x = 0;

    if (n == 0)
    {
        return infinite;
    }
    if (n > 1)
    {
        while (n >>= 1)
        {
            ++x;
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static const T infinite((std::numeric_limits<T>::max)());
```

will work: the extra brackets blocks the macro expansion.

Comment: Ahh clever and simple!  Thanks very much :-)

Comment: Plus one for evil genius. But I prefer my solution though: why should `windows.h` mean our rewriting our code in such a way?

Comment: @bath ours is not to reason why, ours is but to wrestle with many million line legacy code bases and die.  The undef solution ends up being a war with every system include in every file, plus a sweep of all legacy use of min/max.

Comment: @Yakk: Regarding “The undef solution ends up being a war with every system include in every file, plus a sweep of all legacy use of min/max.” No, that is not so. To wit, the MinGW g++ `windows.h` does not define `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 3):

`windows.h` relies on a number of configuration symbols.

To use this header properly you need to wrap it, so as to get the same definitions everywhere.

A minimum wrapper header:

```
#pragma once

#undef  STRICT
#define STRICT
#undef  NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX
#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef  WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
```

With both g++ and MSVC **`WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`** reduces the number of lines to about half. With g++ we're talking about a reduction roughly 60 000 → 30 000 lines, and with MSVC a reduction 300 000 → 150 000 lines. A reduction of 150 000 lines for the translation unit is IMHO significant enough to define this symbol by default.

**`UNICODE`** causes `<windows.h>` macros like `CreateWindow` (and all the thousands upon thousands of similar function name macros) to expand to `CreateWindowW` (Unicode `wchar_t` variant) instead of `CreateWindowA` (ANSI `char` compatibility variant), and causes `TCHAR` to map to `wchar_t` instead of `char`. For the runtime library you may consider defining **`_UNICODE`** corresponding to `UNICODE`, and error out if `_MBCS` is defined.

**`NOMINMAX`** is the main solution to your problem: it suppresses definitions of the `min` and `max` macros. Quite possibly it's then still necessary to add fixup to the GDI+ headers, which at least originally relied on Windows' `min` and `max`. But due to Microsoft's other bad practices you generally need to wrap every Windows header anyway.

**`STRICT`** is now defined by default, but it doesn't hurt to define it. It gives C++-compatible declarations of some functions, e.g. IIRC `DialogBox` and friends.

The main configuration not covered above is **`_WIN32_WINNT`**, the main version macro. There are also a handful of other version macros, reflecting that different parts of the Windows API have been updated separately and via different means, e.g. via updates of Internet Explorer (!). An attempt was made some years ago to unify the mess via yet another versioning scheme, of course with its own macro, but also with that thing you would mainly define `_WIN32_WINNT` and let the other version macros be derived.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need to `#include` `<windows.h>`, I use

```
#define byte byte_for_windows_include
#include <windows.h>
#undef byte

#ifdef max
#    undef max
#endif
#ifdef min
#    undef min
#endif
```

`<windows.h>` also emits a definition for `byte` into the global namespace, which can be troublesome.

It's also a good idea to `#define STRICT` too.

`#define`ing `NOMINMAX` has proved unreliable in the past.